# VSCode - Output window says "UnicodeEncodeError" when I try to print unicode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just started to use VSCode on some python scripts. When I try to print something like:

```
print('%s' % string.decode('utf-8'))
```

I get following error in output window:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 16-20: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I know it probably because the output stream is ascii only, but I can't find a place to change it... , either I missed it, or it just the way it is?

I'm using v0.10.8 on Win7 64bit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `.decode('utf-16')`

Comment: The same code work in IEP (another python IDE). So it's not code issue.

Comment: Hmm, if you catch UnicodeEncodeError and print `repr(string)`, what does it print in VSCode and in other IDE's?

Comment: The output is '\xe6\xad\xa6\xe6\xb1\x89\xe6\xac\xa3\xe6\x99\xaf\xe9\x80\x9a' which is utf-8 encoded.

Comment: Hi, this is a bug in the Python extension for VS Code, and a bug has been raised against this. Hopefully someone will be able to assist in resolving this issue. Details of underlying issue has been raised here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657455/stdout-encoding-of-python-process-launched-form-nodejs-spawn

Answer (score 6):

I suffer the same problem, it's caused by the the plugin -- Code Runner.

Please check the discussions here:

- [UnicodeEncodeError](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/197)
- [Output utf8 chars incorrect](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/25#issuecomment-263170907)

It suggest to write these into VSCode setting file:

```
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "python": "set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8 && python"
    }
}
```

if, it doesn't work, you can use this (run the script in terminal):

```
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct

```
arabic_bytes=b'\xd9\x83\xd9\x84\xd8\xa7 \xd8\xa8\xd8\xaf\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa9 \xd9\x88\xd8\xa8\xd8\xaf\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8a\xd8\xa9'

print('%s' % arabic_bytes.decode('utf-8'))
```

And you should see   كلا بداية وبداية

It is possible that your Byte string is corrupted in which case change you decode to be

```
 arabic_bytes.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
```

Comment: Same error. I forgot to mention that I'm (still) using Python2.

Comment: The command I shared - also works in Python2.7...  Can you share what your "string" looks like ?? Do a type(string) to confirm it's data type.

Comment: Are you running it in VSCode and see the result in output window?

Comment: Sorry I only run Unix/Linux - no experience with that IDE. How about 
   import print      
   pprint.pprint(string)

Comment: I ran successfully in other IDEs. I should make it clear in subject that this question is about VSCode. Thanks.

Comment: Switch IDE's - PyCharm works for me - or iPython/Jupiter Notebook