# unicodeEncoderError when I am trying to beautifulsoup a website

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, beautifulsoup, html-helper

[encodingerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGpHd.png)  I am trying to scrape the mentioned website on the pics but I keep getting this error, and I am a total noob in programming so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Try refrain from posting images of code or links to images of code. Just paste the code into the question, this is to ensure your question has the highest chance of being answered.

Comment: Simply, run your code without `code-runner` as `python code.py`, if that's works . let me know so i can give you a configuration to be inserted to your `vscode` to run it with code runner without issue.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, i tried it and it didnt work can you help me with that configuration ? @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Comment: @QuietStorm check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571890/vscode-output-window-says-unicodeencodeerror-when-i-try-to-print-unicode