# properly converting special chars in python byte string

Tags: python, string, python-unicode

Tried to look through a few similar threads, but still confused:

I have a byte string with some special characters (for a double quote in my case) like below. What's the easiest way to properly convert it to a string, so that the special characters are mapped correctly?

```
b = b'My groovy str\xe2\x80\x9d is now fixed'
```

Update: regarding decode('utf-8')

```
>>> b = b'My groovy str\xe2\x80\x9d is now fixed'
>>> b_converted = b.decode("utf-8") 
>>> b_converted
'My groovy str\u201d is now fixed'
>>> print(b_converted)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u201d' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
b_converted = b.decode("utf-8")
```

Converted from:

```
b'My groovy str\xe2\x80\x9d is now fixed'
```

To:

```
My groovy str” is now fixed
```

Comment: That works for the particular example included in the question, but it's important to note that there are lots of different choices that can be passed to `encode`.  You really need to know the source of the byte string to know the proper parameter.

Comment: Here's what I get: >>> b.decode('utf-8')
'My groovy str\u201d is now fixed'

Comment: Python 3.6, but it doesn't work for me in 2.7 either. Could it be because I typed those special characters in?

Comment: I mean, I have just copied your line of code in a Python online editor (Python 3) and, by applying `decode`, it works... Try to do so and let me know.

Comment: Just tried - updated the question with the snapshot of how it looks for me

Comment: I think it is a problem with the console. Can you set a breakpoint before printing the variable and see if the variable is good? Are you using VS Code? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571890/vscode-output-window-says-unicodeencodeerror-when-i-try-to-print-unicode, where it a similar problem is explained on the printing.

Comment: Thanks, - it's a plain unix interface, there's no VS Code

Comment: Then, probably it's because the interface doesn't fully support utf-8

Comment: I think you're right - I get some funny behavior, when I export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

Comment: `'\u201d' == '”'`.  The display difference is that on Python3 if the Unicode is a printable character *in the encoding supported by the terminal* it will print the character, else it will display an escape code in a `repr()` string.  On Python 2 only ASCII printable characters are un-escaped.  when you actually `print` to the terminal you get the `str()` is used and non-printable characters give `UnicodeEncodeError` if the character can't be printed in the terminal's encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.decode(encoding)` on a byte string to convert it to Unicode.

Encoding can not always be determined and depends on the source.  In this case it is clearly `utf8`.

Ideally when reading text strings the API used to read the data can specify the encoding or in the case of website requests detect it from response headers, so you don't need to `.decode` explicitly, for example:

```
with open('input.txt',encoding='utf8') as file:
    text = file.read()
```

or

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://example.com')
print(response.encoding)
print(response.text) # translated from encoding
```

Comment: Thank you, please see my comment above. Maybe it doesn't work b/c decode doesn't escape special chars, but 'unicode escape' didn't work for me either

Comment: @LazyCat That's due to your execution environment.  Your output terminal using a code page that doesn't support all Unicode characters.  `print` is using the `ascii` codec to *encode* the Unicode string to the terminal.  What are you running Python under (for example, "Windows 10 64-bit, cmd.exe terminal").

Comment: Thanks, just under plain linux, so wasn't expecting such issues

Comment: @LazyCat To be clear, the `.decode()` is working and the `print` is doing `.encode('ascii')` to the terminal and failing.  This indicates the terminal isn't configured correctly for UTF-8.  I'm not using Linux, but IIRC Python uses `LC_ALL` environment variable to detect the terminal encoding.  That's a separate problem than your original question, and there are plenty of existing answers on SO dealing with `print` issues.

Comment: Try `export LC_ALL='en_US.utf8'`