# how to store special character in python dictionary

Tags: python, special-characters

i have problems to store the special (mostly unicode for escape it). here is the code

```
class jsonDefaultTemplate:

def jsonEscapeList():
   x = [{"\t":"u0009","\n":"u000A","r":"u000D","!":"u0021",""":"u0022","#":"u0023","$":"u0024","%":"u0025","&":"u0026","'":"u0027","(":"u0028",")":"u0029","*":"u002A","+":"u002B",",":"u002C","-":"u002D",".":"u002E","/":"u002F",":":"u003A",";":"u003B","<":"u003C","=":"u003D",">":"u003E","?":"u003F","@":"u0040","[":"u005B","\":"u005C","]":"u005D","^":"u005E","_":"u005F","`":"u0060","{":"u007B","|":"u007C","}":"u007D","~":"u007E",",":"u0082","ƒ":"u0083",""":"u0084","...":"u0085","†":"u0086","‡":"u0087","^":"u0088","‰":"u0089","Š":"u008A","<":"u008B","Œ":"u008C","`":"u0091","'":"u0092","•":"u0095","–":"u0096","--":"u0097","~":"u0098","™":"u0099","š":"u009A",">":"u009B","œ":"u009C","":"u00A0","¡":"u00A1","¢":"u00A2","£":"u00A3","¤":"u00A4","¥":"u00A5","|":"u00A6","§":"u00A7","¨":"u00A8","©":"u00A9","ª":"u00AA","«":"u00AB","¬":"u00AC","-":"u00AD","®":"u00AE","¯":"u00AF","˚":"u00B0","±":"u00B1","´":"u00B4","µ":"u00B5","¶":"u00B6","·":"u00B7","¸":"u00B8","1":"u00B9","º":"u00BA","»":"u00BB","¼":"u00BC","½":"u00BD","¾":"u00BE","¿":"u00BF","À":"u00C0","Á":"u00C1","Â":"u00C2","Ã":"u00C3","Ä":"u00C4","Å":"u00C5","Æ":"u00C6","Ç":"u00C7","È":"u00C8","É":"u00C9","Ê":"u00CA","Ë":"u00CB","Ì":"u00CC","Í":"u00CD","Î":"u00CE","Ï":"u00CF","Ð":"u00D0","Ñ":"u00D1","Ò":"u00D2","Ó":"u00D3","Ô":"u00D4","Õ":"u00D5","Ö":"u00D6","×":"u00D7","Ø":"u00D8","Ù":"u00D9","Ú":"u00DA","Û":"u00DB","Ü":"u00DC","ß":"u00DF","à":"u00E0","á":"u00E1","â":"u00E2","ã":"u00E3","ä":"u00E4","å":"u00E5","æ":"u00E6","ç":"u00E7","è":"u00E8","é":"u00E9","ê":"u00EA","ë":"u00EB","ì":"u00EC","í":"u00ED","î":"u00EE","ï":"u00EF","ñ":"u00F1","ò":"u00F2","ó":"u00F3","ô":"u00F4","õ":"u00F5","ö":"u00F6","÷":"u00F7","ø":"u00F8","ù":"u00F9","ú":"u00FA","û":"u00FB","ü":"u00FC","ý":"u00FD","ÿ":"u00FF"}]
return x
```

```
here is printing statement:
a = jsonDefaultTemplate.jsonEscapeList()
print(a)

occasionally error encourter:
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u02da' in position ....

the last error on running:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\admin\Documents\git\*******\lib\defaultJsonclass.py", line 64, in <module>
    print(a)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u02da' in position 946: character maps to <undefined>
```

i want to store the special character to check in json string in python dictionary for compare and escape on string check function. I already check for other topic for unicode encode and other topic too. Anyone have same problems or have working around that plz guide me. Thank you for your times

Comment: python2 or python3?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, plus `'\u02da'` is not in your code snippet. Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your code just returns your escape character mappings as a list, when it runs, it just returns that list containing the entered dict. 

There must be some actual code you're running to produce your error, what is that?

Comment: @alec_djinn, the character is ˚.

Comment: Do you get this error when trying to print the dict to your terminal? (Rather than when you create or access the dictionary?)

Comment: @ThomasKimber i just reproduce the error, sorry for inconvenient

Comment: @alec_djinn i did recheck it and it still the same error

Comment: @anhphan What if you simply remove the `print(a)` ? If you don't try to print that character to your terminal, do you still get the error?

Comment: @slothrop it happen when i try to print the dict in vscode studio code( i think it use the same interpreter as the one which is python version installed too). i am trying to create and access it now to see in which i can progress more

Comment: @slothrop is it a problems to display the "special character" in terminal, i saw it show error. Something come to special character which bother me to debug first before continue

Comment: The problem could be something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35571890/vscode-output-window-says-unicodeencodeerror-when-i-try-to-print-unicode (i.e. VSCode settings need to be modified to have Python write to the terminal with UTF-8 encoding)

Comment: There are so many comments but none pointed out that the dictionary string is malformed, it uses `"""` to represent double quote, and is a syntax error, causes the interpreter to mistakenly think all the following characters are part of the string. It should be `'"'`. This error is so obvious why so many high rep users failed to notice it is a mystery.

Comment: Thank Everyone, it is solution. "The problem could be something like this: stackoverflow.com/questions/35571890/… (i.e. VSCode settings need to be modified to have Python write to the terminal with UTF-8 encoding) ". it is "code runner extension", after follow the guide it show correct output. And thank you for the time

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution(thank you everyone):
"
The problem could be something like this: stackoverflow.com/questions/35571890/… (i.e. VSCode settings need to be modified to have Python write to the terminal with UTF-8 encoding) – slothrop
"